# Bing Maps: How to disable 'allow location' request

Tags: javascript, .net, maps, bing-maps

I embedded a map onto my page and whenever users visit it, they get the "allow location" prompt like the one on the image below:

[image]

How do I disable this? I've tried to look but couldn't find any resources.

Any piece of information or advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This information is shown because in your code or in the ui context, you're trying to use the real current location of the user.

Check your code or paste it here so we can help you in order to find the line where you're trying to use the current location of the user through its browser.

Comment: @AnimaSola, check in your code for something like Microsoft.Maps.GeoLocationProvider(map);geoLocationProvider.getCurrentPosition();